# "await/async": Why the 2 pieces of code doesn't run the same?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

It's a simple WinForm application to experiment with the await/async keywords. Below is the event handler for a button.

**I quickly click the button twice, the interval is smaller than 3000ms so the background threads are not done yet.**

```
    private Task<String> f()
    {
        return Task.Run<String>(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
            }
        );
    }

    private async void async_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<String> wait_task = f();

        //Code 1, this outputs first 3, and then 3 is REPLACED with 4.
        //this.async_lbl.Text += await wait_task;  //3 -> 4

        //Code 2, this outputs first 3, and then 34.
        //String wait_value = await wait_task;
        //this.async_lbl.Text += wait_value;  //3 -> 34
    }
```

Why the output of 1 and 2 differ?

Thanks!

### ADD

Below is the reflected code:

3 -> 34

```
// WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1
private async void async_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<string> task = this.f();
    string str = await task;
    Label expr_AA = this.async_lbl;
    expr_AA.Text += str;
}
```

3 -> 4

```
// WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1
private async void async_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<string> task = this.f();
    Label label = this.async_lbl;
    label.Text += await task;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is explained in the C# language specification. [Section 14.3.2: Compound Assignment](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/14.13.2.htm):

> [T]he operation is evaluated as x = x op y, except that x is evaluated only once.

The line

```
this.async_lbl.Text += await wait_task;
```

expands to

```
this.async_lbl.Text = this.async_lbl.Text + await wait_task;
```

At the time the line is executed, `this.async_lbl.Text` is the empty string. The right hand side therefore evaluates to

```
"" + await wait_task
```

The code then awaits the result of the task, and it returns 4. The result of the expression is therefore

```
"" + "4"
```

which is `"4"`. which is then assigned as the text of `this.async_lbl`. Notice that the starting value of `this.async_lbl.Text` is used *before* the `await` occurs.

On the other hand,

```
string wait_value = await wait_task;
this.async_lbl.Text += wait_value;
```

expands to

```
string wait_value = await wait_task;
this.async_lbl.Text = this.async_lbl.Text + wait_value;
```

This time, the code awaits the `wait_task`, which returns `"4"`. But in the meantime, the value of `this.async_lbl.Text` changed to `"3"`. Then the line

```
this.async_lbl.Text = this.async_lbl.Text + wait_value;
```

executes, and the right-hand side is now

```
"3" + "4"
```

which evaluates to `"34`".

Comment: So, it is the compound-assignment-evaluate-only-once rule. It really has nothing to do with the thread timing. Many thanks.

Comment: I think this rule is specific to the C# compiler design/implementation. Why make it this way? I think it's possible to make the evaluation dynamic to reflect the latest change. And that's more reasonable.

Comment: Whether or not the current design is "good", the fact remains that it is the current language design, so you have to deal with it regardless.